# Login application - reads only the last entry in my database

Tags: android, authentication

I am creating a simple, sort of login app in Android. The point of the app (for now) is to open a new activity if the username and password are correct.
The username and password are stored in a database. The log in is done after comparing the username and password that are entered in the EditText fields with the ones in the database. If they are a match, than new activity is opened.
The issue that I am having is that only the last user can log in, meaning that the new activity is opened only if username and password of the last user in the table are entered as log in information. In my table I have created 5 users each one having a different user and password. But, when I enter the information for the first user in the login in screen (if I enter user and pass of some other user in the EditText field), nothing happens. It is displaying a toast that I have programmed as if the info about that user is not stored in the table.
Here is the code that I am using for this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        user = findViewById(R.id.userEditTextField);
        pass = findViewById(R.id.passEditTextField);

    }

    public void loginButtonClick(View view) {

        if (drSchDBHelper == null) {
            drSchDBHelper = new DrSchDBHelper(this);
        }

        db = drSchDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        String savedUser = null;
        String savedPass = null;

        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM LoginTable", null);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                savedUser = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_NAME_USER));
                savedPass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD));
            }

            if (user.getText().toString().equals(savedUser) && pass.getText().toString().equals(savedPass)) {


                Intent userLoginIntent = new Intent(this, UserLoginPage.class);
                startActivity(userLoginIntent);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please,check your Username and Password, or create an account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error:", e.toString());
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        }
    }
```

If anyone has an idea, or an advice, link or anything that could point me in the desired direction, I would appreciate it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are only comparing the last username and password. Change it to this (Also you need to call this on background thread, as this is currently doing disk read on UI thread, aka main thread):

```
        try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM LoginTable", null);
        boolean loggedIn = false;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            savedUser = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_NAME_USER));
            savedPass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD));

            if (user.getText().toString().equals(savedUser) && pass.getText().toString().equals(savedPass)) {

                loggedIn = true;
                Intent userLoginIntent = new Intent(this, UserLoginPage.class);
                startActivity(userLoginIntent);
                break;

            }
        }

         if (!loggedIn) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please,check your Username and Password, or create an account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error:", e.toString());
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you ABS for your answer. I have tried your advice, but I still get the same result. The cursor reads only the last entry. However, I didn't run that in a separate thread. But I don' think that the separate thread will solve the issue. Or am I mistaking?? Also, please don't mind me asking, but your suggestion of a solution is almost the same as mine...except the one boolean variable...So how is that going to get the needed result? Or am I overseeing something?? thank you for your answer...I am farily new at this, by the way...

Comment: @PetarSindjic The change that I made was to put the if condition within while loop. What it will do is check each username and password. Your if condition was outside of while loop, so your username and password was always set to the last entry before it could reach the if condition.

Comment: You are totally wright. I overlooked that you have re-positioned the IF statement. Thank you. This has solved the problem that I had. However, now when I return back to the login screen and try  to enter another user and pass (to log as a different user) my app reports an error. But I assume that is because the previous user is still logged in, so to say... I will probably need to make a log out button :). thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be better if you do this in such a way that store data from `EditTexts` in some variable then perform validation.
For Example

```
 public boolean isLoginValid(String username, String password) {
        String sql = "Select count(*) from user where username='" + username + "' and password='" + password + "'";
        SQLiteStatement sqLiteStatement = getReadableDatabase().compileStatement(sql);
        long l = sqLiteStatement.simpleQueryForLong();
        sqLiteStatement.close();
        return l == 1;
    }
```

If method returns true, then data exists and new activity should appear.

Comment: Hi Shehryar, Thank you for your comment. I have tried your method, but it didn't work. Maybe I have done something wrong

Comment: I would like to send you the code where I have used your method for you to re check if you like, but it is  to long to fit in a comment